# FAQ для Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предложение

На MSE есть вот такой вопрос со ссылками на все важные обсуждения: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/260198).

1. Предлагаю у нас такой же список завести. За основу взять их список.
2. Если у нас есть свой аналог, то заменить текст и ссылку.
3. Если у нас есть свои важные обсуждения, добавить в список.

Comment: Инициатива отличная! У нас уже она была. Единственное, как мне кажется, список не полный (упущены последнии темы). Скажите, правильно ли я понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ага, вроде оно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky единственное, не ясно. Стоит ли добавлять ссылки на MSE обсуждения, которые у нас не переведены?